# How to install software's by default in new volume Virtual Box Running on Mac

Tags: disk

Initially I had installed Ubuntu 11.10 on VirtualBox running on Mac OS, with hard-disk storage of 8GB. As I was left with only 50MB space, I increased the diskspace on the VirtualBox by another 8 GB (Total 16GB) using Mac terminal.

When I logged into Ubuntu I was seeing 2 volumes 8GB (Original) and 8GN (Newly created). I mounted the new volume and the total diskspace now is shown as 16GB.

The issue is that when downloading any software it gives me an error saying diskspace is low as  its trying to install on Origianl volume which has 50MB space. How do i make new software to install on new volume by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how to increase the size of the disk your virtual machine is using as root.

So while you could use the second disk as storage, you will still not have sufficient space on your root partition.

What you need to do is make a new, larger disk, how much space do you need 4 Gb ?

So make a new 12 Gb (or larger) disk.

Add this new disk to your virtual machine.

Boot the virtual machine with a live CD, ubuntu or gparted.

Use gparted to first copy the ubuntu partition from the old 8 Gb disk to the 12 gb disk. Then enlarge the 8 gb partition to 12 Gb.

Shut down the VM, remove the 8 Gb disk, boot from the 12 Gb disk.

See also

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=10348

http://www.gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual&lang=C

Comment: After booting with GParted Live, where should I be executing the command "dd if=/dev/hdX of=/dev/hdY" In Ubuntu Terminal?

Comment: Yes, terminal will be fine. After using dd you will still need to resize the partition (gparted is easier).